# listening to custom events in created hook vs using "@" in child tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

1. Is there any reason behind listening to custom events through listener in the created hook over using "@" on the child tag on the parent component?

**child**

```
<template>
    <button @click="emitCustomEvent">press on</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        emitCustomEvent() {
            this.$emit('event-name', { message: 'test' })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**parent**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        <ChildComponent @event-name="setMessage" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'
export default {
    components: { ChildComponent },
    data () {
        return {
            message: 'Hello'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setMessage(payload) {
            this.message = payload.message
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

2. On the code above how to listen to emit event **event-name** on the created hook?

Comment: You can't listen to events from the created hook, you could use the native addEventListener method but it's kinda bypassing vue in that case, not really recommended

Comment: @Lk77as far as I know events can be listened using this syntax **    this.$root.$on('..)**

Comment: There is a good explanation with examples in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Programmatic-Event-Listeners)

Comment: Using $root.$on defeat the purpose, you could also do $root.$emit in your component, but you've made your events global when doing that, also those methods are removed on vue 3 so be careful if you plan on migrating to vue 3 someday

Comment: so when migrating to v3 I have to remove all these listener through **this.$root.$on('..')** @Lk77 is there a way to determine wich vue version is used on a project ?

Comment: @nayakhattar yes you will have to remove them, and use something else like a package to do that. Look at the package.json file to see your version. Overall the recommended way is to use [ @  / v-on: ]event-name on the component/element, it will work with both vue2 and vue3 and it's the best way to do it.